# Dynamic button javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, button

had a look for a guide on this but couldn't really find anything specific on it, and thought you guys could help.

I have a javascript file which performs various tasks onLoad. Currently I have 5 buttons in an HTML page but what I would like to do is to is read from an array in the js file and dynamically create a number of buttons depending what was in the array.

Similarly I want the buttons on click to be 'listened' for (alter an array in the js)

I have an idea that I want to read the array elements and set them as the button IDs and create them. Likewise I want to listen to what button has been clicked by its ID and have it alter an array. But how do I actually go about that process?

Cheers

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to do when the button is clicked?

Comment: If I have an array; arr = [0,1,2,4] I want to create buttons with those IDs, and once the buttons are created, I want to then change a different array depending if the button has been clicked; For example a button with ID = 2 and the arr2 = [0,1,3] when clicked would then change that array to arr2 = [0,1,2,3]

Comment: Excellent, I took a wild guess and did just that in my solution. It doesn't behave like a set though... If you click the button twice, it will be added to arr2 twice. Is that what you want? Or do you want it to be added just once?

Comment: My solution below is essentially a JQuery-free version of what @Spycho has done, so take you pick - I'd probably go with Spycho's cos JQuery will make your life much easier in the long run...

Comment: @Spycho Added just once, and then removed on a second click (like a toggle) but that is easy enough for me. Sorry I should have been more clear, I cannot use jQuery but I appreciate your help

Comment: Ah ok. I would go for @DaveRandom's solution then, but with a slight modification to toggle rather than continuously append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var arrayToModify = [];
      window.onload = function () {
        var i, buttonsToCreate, buttonContainer, newButton;
        buttonsToCreate = ['button1','button2','button3','button4','button5'];
        buttonContainer = document.getElementById('this_element_contains_my_buttons');
        for (i = 0; i < buttonsToCreate.length; i++) {
          newButton = document.createElement('input');
          newButton.type = 'button';
          newButton.value = buttonsToCreate[i];
          newButton.id = buttonsToCreate[i];
          newButton.onclick = function () {
            alert('You pressed '+this.id);
            arrayToModify[arrayToModify.length] = this.id;
          };
          buttonContainer.appendChild(newButton);
        }
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='this_element_contains_my_buttons'></div>
    <input type='button' onclick='alert(arrayToModify);' value='Show the buttons I have clicked' />
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I have just added some functionality to track button presses in an array, as requested in the comment above

Comment: I can use this with a bit of playing about as I now see what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you use jQuery for this. It would make it a lot simpler.

Firstly, to create the buttons from an array of button ids you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
var buttons = ['start', 'stop', 'foo', 'bar'];

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    $('<button>')
        .attr('id', buttons[i])
        .text(buttons[i])
        .appendTo('div');
}
```

Next, to listen for the button clicks, you could modify the above as follows:

```
var buttons = ['start', 'stop', 'foo', 'bar'];
var clicks = [];

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    $('<button>')
        .attr('id', buttons[i])
        .text(buttons[i])
        .appendTo('div')
        .click(function(){
            clicks.push(this.id);
        });
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you want to do on-click. Could you elaborate?

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/38c4s/) a jsFiddle demonstrating the solution.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I will have to take @DaveRandom's version

Answer (score 0):

Use the `event` property of the event listener to get the target element, then it's ID:

```
foo.onclick = function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
}
```